# Programming with swift backend and Angular 2 front. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, angular, ionic2, nativescript

I didn't find anything on Google saying about it.. so, is it possible?

i.e discard the XCode's Storyboard and use Angular 2 to make apps.

PS: Swift isn't discartable for me due frameworks and done backend code. I am using FFT algorythm from Swift's AudioKit Framework.

Comment: I don't know XCode Storyboard. Angular apps are running in a browser. If you want to build a browser-based single-page-application, then you can use Angular.

Comment: The front end doesn't care what you're using for the back end. You want to use Swift, then use Swift. An HTTP request is an HTTP request, it's not relevant if you emit it from Swift or from anything else.

Comment: But how do I connect them? If it's possible to make iOS apps using Angular frontend, is it acceptable on Apple's AppStore?

Comment: You can wrap it in an app store compatible package but it will still be a JavaScript app and will connect to your backend in the exact same way that it would if you targeted the browser. The difference is it'll be able to leverage certain device specific capabilities. You will communicate with your blackend by sending JSON back and forth. The key point is that all communication will be in the form of ***serialized*** messages only. Even if your backend were running on the same device, there's no shared memory space. Of course since mobile app can persist local state it might not need a backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 can be used with any compliant web server written in any language. As long as it speaks HTTP correctly it doesn't matter what it's written in.

Angular2 is a front end JavaScript based technology. As long as you have a web viewer that can render HTML and has a standards compliant JavaScript runtime you can make it talk to your back end.

You can wrap it in an app store compatible package but it will still be a JavaScript app and will connect to your backend in the exact same way that it would if you targeted the browser. The difference is it'll be able to leverage certain device specific capabilities. You will communicate with your backend by sending JSON (any format can be used) back and forth.

The key point is that all communication will be in the form of ***serialized*** messages only.

Even if your backend were running on the same device, there's no shared memory space.

Of course since a mobile app can persist it's own state locally it might not need a backend at all. This last point is very domain specific.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not very familiar with the differents ways to make apps for phones. I am just studying swift and still very stuck at xCode, but it will change soon.
I heard that was possible to make Android apps using Angular2. Found it strange because thought that angular2 is just for web. Then I am here asking. Just to make it clear, my idea of using swift frameworks with apps Angular interface will not work...? Is it acceptable on from Apple to put on AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

It could be posibble if you use **Vapor** as your backend *engine*. Take a look at Vapor's [website](https://vapor.codes/) for more info.

Comment: Swift isn't discartable for me due frameworks and done backend code.

Comment: Vapor is Swift !00% ;)

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but I still want to make iOS apps, not just web pages working with Swift server. But I am very thankful knowing that I can let php/java away and use swift on this case too! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DenisCandino it says "Nearly 100x faster than popular web frameworks using Ruby ", which you have to admit is pretty funny